# Preserving indentation in examples section

Tags: r, roxygen

Roxygen have made my work a lot easier and is in most cases nice and intuitive. One thing that I have never figured out though is how to preserve indentation in @examples sections so that the result of `roxygenize("myPackage")` containing

```
#' @examples
#' sapply(1:10, function(i){
#'     x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2),
#'                matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2) + i)
#'     myFunc(x)
#' }
```

would be

```
\examples{sapply(1:10, function(i){
    x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2),
               matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2) + i)
    myFunc(x)
}}
```

instead of

```
\examples{sapply(1:10, function(i){
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2),
matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2) + i)
myFunc(x)
}}
```

It is a small detail but it makes all but the simplest examples unnecessarily hard to read so I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.

**Edit:** This bug was corrected in later versions of roxygen.

Comment: Are you using `roxygen` or `roxygen2`? I'm pretty sure this doesn't happen in roxygen2, and if it does it's a bug, and should be reported.

Comment: I was using plain old `roxygen` but the problem remained after I updated to `roxygen2`. gsk3's solution works for both though but I guess it better be reported anyway. How do I do that?

Comment: Please submit a reproducible bug report at https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/27.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably too much overhead for short examples, but for longer examples you could `@example relative/path/to/example` to pull in a file, which should get the indenting right.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! The overhead isn't that bad too since it only applies to some occasional examples, especially when compared to the prohibitively large burden of manually correcting the indentation.